# How can I generate random mixed letters and numbers in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have the following code so far, this generates letters only. I am looking to get both letters and numbers

```
#Generate random 8 digit number and output to file
    output = File.new("C:/Users/%user%/Desktop/Strings.txt", "w")

    i = 0
     while i < 500
        randomer = (0...8).map{65.+(rand(26)).chr}.join
        output << randomer
        output << "\n"
        i = i+1
     end

    output.close
```

Comment: How about http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html#method-c-urlsafe_base64 ?

Comment: Good point - *how random* do these need to be?

Comment: Doesn't need to be too random as they are just codes for parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
def random_tuple(length)
    letters_and_numbers = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
    answer = ""
    length.times { |i| answer << letters_and_numbers[rand(36)] }
    answer
end

output = ""
500.times { |i| output << random_tuple(8) + "\n" }
```

You could also have the function append the newline, but I think this way is more general.

Comment: Is there a way to add a new line into this so each value appears on a separate line.

Comment: This adds each character to a new line but I need each 8 digit value on a separate line.

Comment: That works fine but you have to remove the output="" for it to work correctly.

Answer (score 3):

```
(('a'..'z').to_a + ('0'..'9').to_a).sample( 8 ).join
```

This *is* random, but will not re-use any number/letter, so it does not cover all possible strings.

Comment: Doesn't re-use any numbers/letters! Doh!

Comment: This gives me a syntax error expecting keyword_end
  randomer = ('a'..'z').to_a + ('0'..'9').to_a).sample( length ).join
                                               ^

Comment: @Ninja2k. A typo, fixed now. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: It doesn't use all the possible combinations though. For your use, this would start to matter for an 8-letter code when you have a few tens of products (when you have 613 products, there is a 50/50 chance two of them will have the same code, at least unless you weed out duplicates!) Other posters can get you up to a few tens of thousands of products with the same 8 letters . . .

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
i = 0
while i < 500
    randomer = (1..8).map { (('a'..'z').to_a + ('0'..'9').to_a)[rand(36)] }.join
    output << randomer
    output << "\n"
    i = i+1
end

output.close
```

Enjoy.

Comment: How do I integrate this into my current formula?

Answer (score 2):

Use `SecureRandom.hex(10)` his generate letters and numbers in 0-9 and a-f

or

```
SecureRandom.base64.delete('/+=')[0, 8]
```

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html

Answer (score 2):

All digits and letters are used in base 36:

```
max = 36**8
500.times.map{ rand(max).to_s(36).rjust(8,'0') } #rjust pads short strings with '0'
```